# websocket, java and netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, websocket

I am trying to recreate an Oracle tutorial for websocket, and I assume they would assume NetBeans. The manual says and I quote:

"Deploying your EchoServer WebSocket endpoint is particularly simple. You need to compile the source file, include the class file in the WAR file, and deploy the WAR file."

But I thought Netbeans compiles automatically, and certainly when you deploy. Am I missing something?  I think yes, because I can't get a return message from the server.  So I am running Java 7.51, with Glassfish 4.0. I think I am connecting to the endpoint, but no return message from the server. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package websock;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;


@ServerEndpoint("/echo")

public class EchoServer {
@OnMessage
String echo(String incomingMessage){
    return "I got this (" + incomingMessage + ")"
            + " so I am sending it back!";
}

}
```

And the HTML, etc:

```
<script>
        var echo_websocket;

        var init = function(){
            output = document.getElementById('output');
            var btnSend = document.getElementById('sendMsg');
            btnSend.addEventListener('click', send_echo);
        };

        var send_echo = function(){
            var wsUri = 'ws://localhost:8080/websock/echo';
            writeToScreen('Connecting to ' + wsUri);
            echo_websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
            echo_websocket.onopen = function(evt){
              writeToScreen ('Connected!');
              doSend(textID.value);
            };

            echo_websocket.onmessage = function(evt){
              writeToScreen('Received message ' + evt.data);
              echo_websocket.close();
            };

            echo_websocket.onerror = function(evt){
              writeToScreen('<span style="color:red;">' + evt.data + 
                      '</span>');
              echo_websocket.close();
            };
        };

        var doSend = function(message){
            echo_websocket.send(message);
            writeToScreen('message sent: ' + message);

        };

        var writeToScreen = function(message){
          var pre = document.createElement('p');
          pre.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
          pre.innerHTML = message;
          output.appendChild(pre);
        };

        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);


    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="textID"><br>

        <button id="sendMsg">Send Message</button>


    </div>

    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Executing this with the string "why doesn't this work", gets the following output:

```
Connecting to ws://localhost:8080/websock/echo

Connected!

message sent: why doesn't this work
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading. It was a syntax error. I neglected to declare public String...